# How to read data blob from Apache Derby DB with python jaydebeapi?

Tags: python, database, blob, derby, jaydebeapi

I am trying to import data from a a local derby database into python using the jaydebeapi. I am running python 3.6 from PyCharmCE:

```
import jaydebeapi as jdbc

conn = jdbc.connect("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver", "jdbc:derby://address:port/db_name", ["user", "pwd"], "path/to/derbyclient-10.14.2.jar")
curs = conn.cursor()

curs.execute("select ITEM from TABLENAME")
rec = curs.fetchone()[0]

curs.execute("select BLOB from TABLENAME")
rec = curs.fetchone()[0]

curs.close()
conn.close()
```

While everythong goes well for the first query, i am having troubles with the data blob. I receive the following runtime error:

```
Process finished with exit code 134 (interrupted by signal 6: SIGABRT)
```

The blob data size is approx. 200kB. At runtime the rec variable is of type org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientBlob - found that a bit puzzling ...no idea if it contributes to the solution.

Thx in advance for any hints!

Comment: Can you gather more information? Does your python interface produce any log files? Class `org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientBlob` is an appropriate class to be used in the client code when retrieving a data blob, so you'll need to try to look deeper to figure out the actual problem. The Derby code will throw a SQLException if it has a problem; can you figure out where that exception is caught and print it out?

Comment: Thanks @BryanPendleton: I tried to find out more about the terminating error. I think I can factorize the problem now. The error code seems to be related to my IDE. The code terminates fine, if I run it inside the shell.
There remains the problem, that I am clueless what to do with the `org.apache.derby.client.am.ClientBlob` object. I try to extract the data, but I failed to turn it into a stream or anything alike. How can I cast it in a way that python will give me access to the data?

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast it. The Derby `ClientBlob` implements the Java SQL Blob interface https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Blob.html It's a standard part of the Java JDBC API. So you simply invoke the Blob Interface's methods on it.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be [an issue of JPype 0.7.5](https://github.com/jpype-project/jpype/issues/765) (and maybe before). This might be fixed in the upcoming 0.7.6.

Also it might be worth trying the JayDeBeApi 1.2.3 if you haven't done so yet.